# Mini laptop battery question

Tags: laptop

I have a HP Mini laptop. If I stay near an external electrical power source, is it right to power the laptop from this source if the battery is not empty?

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/170646/is-a-laptop-damaged-by-always-keeping-it-plugged-in/170649#170649

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally yes, I'd use the power source instead of the battery when available.

But keep in mind...

A battery should not be left charged in a dormant state for a very long time. After it is fully charged you should use it at least once every few weeks at a **bare minimum** to extend battery life. If you are using an older lithium-ion battery, avoid letting its charge drop to 0. Lithium-ion batteries typically have what is called a **discharge/charge cycle** of 300-500.

For more information, check out [Battery University](http://www.batteryuniversity.com/index.htm).

Comment: I believe the rule "use it at least once every few weeks" only applies to lead accumulators; I've never heard it for LiIon accumulators. The page to linke to does not mention it either. The only caveat is that a LiIon must never discharge completely; thus when stored for months, you will need to recharge occasionally to make up for self-discharge.

Answer (score -1):

[BatteryCare](http://batterycare.net/en/index.html) is an excellent freeware tool that can help you manage your battery health and power savings.

> BatteryCare is a software created to
>   optimize the usage and performance of
>   the modern laptop's battery. It
>   monitors the battery's discharge
>   cycles and helps increasing it's
>   autonomy and improving its lifetime.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

You shuould.Avoid allowing the battery to drop below 5% of capacity because most new versions of the Windows OS will automatically put your laptop computer in a forced “hibernation” mode which may cause the loss of some projects you are working on.Only remove or install a laptop battery when your computer is turned off, this will avoid any current surge that could harm your new battery.

Comment: The whole point of hibernation is to retain everything that was in memory, allowing you to restore when you have access to an alternate power source. You *will* lose what you are working on if it *doesn't* hibernate and instead just runs out of power while it's running!