# Is it safe to leave a laptop always plugged in to power and use it for longer times?

Tags: laptop, power, intel-core-i7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to use a laptop on battery or on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-a-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power)

I have HP dv6 i7 and I work on it for almost 15 hours constantly. Due to power problems in my area because of electricity load shedding, I keep my laptop plugged to power even when the battery is fully charged.

- Is it safe to keep my laptop plugged in all the time?
- Is it safe to use my laptop for 15 hours every day?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to use a laptop on battery or on AC power?](http://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-a-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power) and [Is a laptop damaged by always keeping it plugged in?](http://superuser.com/questions/170646/is-a-laptop-damaged-by-always-keeping-it-plugged-in)

Answer (score 1):

Plugged in all day: -  It's a complicated question, with even more complicated answers, since different manufacturers give slightly different answers: Lenovo and Dell reportedly say your battery should be fine if your computer stays plugged in; HP says you should remove the battery if you are running on AC power for weeks at a time; Apple suggests you should unplug and run off the battery every once in a while.

Safe to use for 15 hours a day - Yes. As long as you have it properly ventilated e.g not on a bed or something else that would block the vents.

Comment: I am using it on a hard table.

Comment: Did You give the link to the website where you found the battery info may be there is more useful info for me.

Comment: @AlfredJames. Link - http://www.zdnet.com/blog/gadgetreviews/should-you-run-your-laptop-on-battery-or-charger-power/586. Table should be fine for ventilation.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend leaving a battery overcharging all the time, I would decharge at least once a week to refresh the charge. In saying that, i wouldn't do a complete decharge only to 10-15%.

Once a month perform a complete decharge and overnight recharge.

I would recommend getting a UPS which will assist in keeping the power clean, backup power available and you can maybe limit the time on charge.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop plugged all the time is completely safe but it is reduces your battery life.
Try to discharge once a week.
You can also try Lifetime optimizer that will keep your battery always at 70%-80% and it will never be fully charged.
And for laptop to use 15 hours a day is also totally safe.